# How to execute a task based on a condition in a procedure?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, I am able to execute a task in a procedure like below. And the task runs perfectly.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_AND_EXECUTE_TASK()
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE SQL
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
    EXECUTE TASK TASK_DEMO.TASK_1;
$$;
```

But when I tried to add a condition, I can't seem to get it work. The conditoin is if a query has result, then execute the task, if no result, then do nothing.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_AND_EXECUTE_TASK()
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE SQL
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
DECLARE
  v_count INT;
BEGIN
  -- Retrieve the count of rows
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count
  FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES 
  WHERE 
      GRANTED_BY IN ('AAD_PROVISIONER')
      AND DATE(CREATED_ON) = CURRENT_DATE;
 
  -- Check if the count is greater than 0, then execute the task
  IF v_count > 0 THEN
    EXECUTE TASK TASK_DEMO.TASK_1;
    RETURN 'Task executed successfully.';
  ELSE
    RETURN 'No results found. Task not executed.';
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```

I also tried the code below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CHECK_AND_EXECUTE_TASK()
  RETURNS STRING
  LANGUAGE SQL
  EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
$$
  -- Check if the query returns any results
  WITH result_count AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.GRANTS_TO_ROLES 
    WHERE 
        GRANTED_BY IN ('AAD_PROVISIONER')
        AND DATE(CREATED_ON) = CURRENT_DATE
  )
  SELECT CASE
           WHEN cnt > 0 THEN EXECUTE TASK TASK_DEMO.TASK_1
           ELSE 'No results found. Task not executed.'
         END
  FROM result_count;
$$;
```

Can someone shed some light please?

Comment: The solution is: Enclose the if condition in braces.

--  IF (v_count > 0) THEN

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: Enclose the if condition in braces.
IF (v_count > 0) THEN